# Syntax error with IP Address format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and am running into an error message.  I am following a tutorial and am not sure if my error is because of the version of python I am using.

```
HostIP = input("Enter Host IP: ")
```

I get a syntax error once I add the second period.  192.168 gives no error.  192.168. - error begins.  I am trying to write a script that will be using the socket module.  Any guidance would be helpful.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using python2.7 in which, the `input` method instantly does `eval()` on the input. Use `raw_input` instead to get the string:

```
HostIP = raw_input("Enter Host IP: ")
```

`input` in python3 works similar to python2's `raw_input` in that it gives you a string but `input` in python2 tries to evaluate the input.

Therefore, when you input `192.168`, it immediately converts that to double however, when you do `192.168.`, it is unable to recognize it and thus raises an error.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I haven't played with v3 yet.